# Pegar posição da arraylist que esta em foco no ViewPager

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma arraylist de imagens que é mostrada em um ViewPager, até ai tudo bem, esta mostrando toda a arraylist normalmente.

Mas como faço para pegar o ViewPager que está em foco?
Ou seja pegar a posição certa da arraylist que está sendo visualizada pelo ViewPager

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Galeria> images;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        ImagePagerAdapter(ArrayList<Galeria> images) {
            this.images = images;
            inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {
            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
            assert imageLayout != null;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
            Log.i("POSITION",""+position);

... o resto do código não importa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar a posição que está sendo exibida, basta usar o método [`ViewPager.getCurrentItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()), ele fornece a posição referente ao item que está sendo exibido do `PagerAdapter` no momento.

Para acessar a imagem, basta acessar a instância do `PagerAdapter`, seja por uma variável local da sua `Activity` ou usando o [`ViewPager.getAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getAdapter()).

Comment: burrice minha.. estava procurando isto no adapter